# Help writing getstring function

Tags: c, getstring

Im having some trouble writing a getstring function, this is what I have so far.

Regards,
V

```
const char* getstring()
{


    char *buffer;
    int i = 255;

    buffer = (char *)malloc(i*sizeof(char));

    *buffer = getchar();
    while ( *buffer != '\n' )
    {
        buffer++;
        *buffer = getchar();
    }
    *buffer = '\0';

    const char* _temp = buffer;
    return _temp;
}


int main()
{
    char* temp = getstring();

    for ( ;temp++ ; *temp != '\0')
    {
        printf("%c", *temp);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting `_temp` to `buffer` when the latter points at the terminating `'\0'` of the string.

Move the line:

```
const char* _temp = buffer;
```

to be immediately after the line:

```
buffer = (char *)malloc(i*sizeof(char));
```

so that `_temp` is pointing to the start of the buffer.

You have some other problems:

1. Don't use the name `_temp` - names with a leading underscore are reserved;
2. You need to test that you don't write more than `i` bytes into the buffer;
3. You should test for `malloc()` returning `NULL`;
4. You need to test for `getchar()` returning `EOF`.  This will mean you need to store the `getchar()` result in a variable of type `int` before you assign it to `*buffer`;
5. As Michael Mrozek points out in a comment, the expressions in your `for` loop are the wrong way around.

...and as a point of style, `sizeof(char)` is always 1, so multiplying by it is unnecessary; and casting the result of `malloc()` is unnecessary in C and considered undesirable (unlike C++, where it is required).

Comment: Minor sidenote not worthy of its own answer: the for loop arguments are backwards

Comment: Yes made all of the changes and its working fine now.

Not sure even how the for loop got so contorted, It must of got worped at some point when I was experimenting.

Thanks,
V

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use

```
char buffer[255];
scanf("%254s", &buffer);
```

or

```
char* buffer = readline("GO GO GO:");
```

Comment: Or: fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);

Comment: No this isn't homework. I suppose I could of mentioned that the function is to get strings from serial on an ARM MCU but I didn't think it was relevant.

I dont think any of them options will work, 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
const char* _temp = buffer;
```

Move the above statement just after the call to `malloc`

***Important:***
**Free** the memory allocated to `buffer` after its use in `main()`.

```
free(temp);
```

Comment: Yes forgot to do that,
Thanks,
V

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of the allocated pointer - the value returned by `malloc()` - immediately after calling `malloc()` so you can pass it back to the caller.  You should also check for EOF as well as newline - and that requires an `int` (not a `char`) to hold the value from `getchar()`.  At minimum!